# windows 7 not generating txt report

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, windows-7, batch-processing

I want to generate a txt file with my dns history. Although the batch script executes just fine on windows 8, when i run it on windows 7 it simply creates a blank txt file. Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Here's the batch script

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "baseName=dnshistory"

    set "count=0"
    for /f "delims=%baseName%." %%a in (
        'dir /b /o-d "%baseName%*.txt" 2^>nul'
    ) do ( set /a "count=%%a+1" & goto saveData )

:saveData
    ipconfig /displaydns | find "Record Name" > "%baseName%%count%.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is you Windows 7 version in English too ?

Open a CMD windows and test just the command :

```
ipconfig /displaydns | find /i "Record Name"
```

and look if something is displayed.

If not, try just the command :

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

and look the language used Then correct your code with the correct words.

IE in Portuguese it will be :

```
ipconfig /displaydns | find /i "Nome do Registro"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for a language independent solution:

```
:saveData
(for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig /displaydns') do (
  echo %%a| find "." |findstr /v /r "[0-9]$"
))>file.txt
```

(take every line, filter those, that have a `.` after a `:` (second token) and filter out all lines that end with a number)

**EDIT** another approach (because the above gives some unwanted lines):

find the first line after every `-----------------` line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ipconfig /displaydns |findstr /n "^" >a.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /c:"    --------------" a.txt') do (
  set /a line=%%a+1
  for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /B "!line!:" a.txt') do echo(%%k 
)
```

Comment: Stephan, in my listing there are unwanted lines that also end with alpha characters.

Comment: @foxidrive: ah yes, I see. The lines "CNAME-Eintrag". I hadn't them with my testings yesterday (or oversaw them). With a little luck `CNAME` is not language dependant (because it's in Capitals), so that it can be filtered out.

Comment: Look at this image Stephan: http://i57.tinypic.com/2ailr38.png  There are several lines that will be included and even the `IPv6` address will be included.  I assume the OP wants every "Record Name" in the output - the screen shot is from `Windows 8.1`